# Can’t link QXT lib

Tags: windows, qt

I have follow pro file:

```
CONFIG += qxt
QXT += core gui
...
```

I’m using QxtFlowView class in project. I’m compiling using qmake and then nmake (VS 2010).

I got linker error:

```
contentorganizerwidget.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declsp
ec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall QxtFlowView::setSelectionModel(class QItem
SelectionModel *)" (__imp_?setSelectionModel@QxtFlowView@@QAEXPAVQItemSelectionM
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show a simple code reproducing the issue? Are you not mixing architectures, debug/release, etc?

Comment: '#include <QxtGui\QxtFlowView>
#include <QtGui> coverFlowView_ = new  QxtFlowView(ui->stackedWidgetPreview);
 coverFlowView_->setSelectionModel(selectionModel_);...

Comment: How can I check debug/release, etc?

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). You keep posting chunks.